# Unable to download and install gurobipy package via pycharm

Tags: python, package, gurobi

I'm using Python 3.7 and Gurobi 8.1.

I want to download the package "gurobipy" through pycharm. I can see the package but not download it due to following error:

"Collecting gurobipy

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gurobipy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gurobipy."

Is the package not suitable for my Phython version (3.7)? Do I need an older version?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajluW.png)

Comment: Yes, you may need an older version of Python. Some of unofficial versions you won't find by pip install can be found here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ than install the file by pip install ./yourFile

Comment: Okay thx in the end I am using anaconda and this works with Gurobi.